# Combine using optional struct variable

Tags: swift, combine

I'm trying to load an array of `SCEvent`s into an array of `EventModel`s using Combine. The variable `imagePath` is optional, which I'd like to translate it to an empty `Data()` in its corresponding `EventModel.imageData` variable.

```swift
struct SCEvent {
    let name: String
    let imagePath: String?
}
```

```swift
struct EventModel {
    let name: String
    let imageData: Data
}
```

The following code seems to work, but I can't help but wonder if it is the most optimal way of doing it:

```swift
func loadEvents(_ events: [SCEvent]) -> AnyPublisher<[EventModel], Error> {
    events.publisher
        .flatMap(loadEvent(_:))
        .collect()
        .eraseToAnyPublisher()
}

func loadEvent(_ event: SCEvent) -> AnyPublisher<EventModel, Error> {
    if let imagePath = event.imagePath {
        return DataDownloader.downloadData(fromPath: imagePath)
                   .map { EventModel(name: event.name, imageData: $0) }
                   .eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }

    return Just(EventModel(name: event.name, imageData: Data())
               .eraseToAnyPublisher()
}
```

Ideally, I'd like to use a single publisher in the `loadEvent` function. Maybe something like this (doesn't work, but serves as an example of what I expect):

```swift
func loadEvent(_ event: SCEvent) -> AnyPublisher<[EventModel], Error> {
    event.imagePath
        .flatMap(DataDownloader.downloadData(_:))
        .replaceNil(with: Data())
        .map {
            EventModel(name: event.name, imageData: $0)
        }
        .eraseToAnyPublisher()
}
```

Which doesn't work because `.replaceNil` should be used after `event.imagePath` to replace a `nil` string. Another possible approach would be:

```swift
func loadEvent(_ event: SCEvent) -> AnyPublisher<[EventModel], Error> {
    event.imagePath
        .replaceNil(with: "")
        .flatMap(
            DataDownloader.downloadData(_:)
                .replaceError(with: Data())
        )
        .map {
            EventModel(name: event.name, imageData: $0)
        }
        .eraseToAnyPublisher()
}
```

But it seems forced. Is it even possible with Combine? Is my initial approach the only valid solution?

Comment: Are you sure you want to map nil image paths to an empty `Data`? That seems like bad design...

Comment: @Sweeper It's just a placeholder to remove boilerplate code from the question. Even if i mapped it to `nil`, the question still remains valid (i guess).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `publisher` of `Optional`, which gives you a publisher that publishes one element if the optional is not nil, and an empty publisher otherwise.

You can then `replaceEmpty(with: Data())`, and `map` to an `EventModel`.

```
func loadEvent(_ event: SCEvent) -> AnyPublisher<EventModel, Error> {
    event.imagePath.publisher
        .flatMap(DataDownloader.downloadData(fromPath:))
        .replaceEmpty(with: Data())
        .map {
            EventModel(name: event.name, imageData: $0)
        }
        .eraseToAnyPublisher()
}
```

However, I don't think replacing with a `Data()` is a good idea. A better design would be to replace with `nil`, in which case you'll have to map to an optional first:

```
struct EventModel {
    let name: String
    let imageData: Data?
}

...

        .flatMap(DataDownloader.downloadData(fromPath:))
        .map { $0 as Data? } // here
        .replaceEmpty(with: nil)
```